# How to let params can exist two types when data source from if else

Tags: javascript, typescript

some situation `data` can be `dataOne` or `dataTwo`, how to let typescript work both of settings ?

```
  const [dataOne, setDataOne] = useState<{ createTime: string }[]>([])
  const [dataTwo, setDataTwo] = useState<{ uploadTime: string }[]>([])

  dataOne[0].createTime // work
  dataTwo[0].uploadTime // work

  const data = dataOne.length > 0 ? dataOne : dataTwo

  data[0].uploadTime // fail
```

Comment: What *should* happen? You show that `data[0].uploadTime` fails but how the point is that TS doesn't know whether it exists or not. Does that mean you have to have a fallback value if it's not there? Or are you trying to make sure the code is only called if valid? Or what?

Comment: Well `dataOne` does not have a `uploadTime` property so of course it fails.

Comment: When data pass if else, I hope data[0] can choose `createTime `or `uploadTime` with typescript.

Comment: Well, you would have to do an `if`/`else` *anyway. You can't conditionally decide what `data` is but then automatically determine whether to use one or another property of it. Not unless you go into polymorphism and create related classes or similar but that's a huge overkill. What you only really need is to use `if (dataOne.length > 0)` then in the `if` use `dataOne[0].createTime` and in the `else` use `dataTwo[0].uploadTime`. It both preserves the correct types and lets you write the correct code. TS won't magically infer which is the correct property otherwise.